# How to give a general label to an align environment that has sub-equations label?

Tags: cross-referencing, align, subequations

I have an aligned environment to show a problem's equation that each subequation has a label. For example:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
& \min_{x} X                                        \label{equ: problem1-a}, \\
\textit{subject to:} & \nonumber \\ 
& x_i \in \{0,1\}  \forall {i \in V}                \label{equ: problem1-b}\\ 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

My problem is that, if I want to reference the problem in the text, I should reference one of the equations like problem1-a or problem1-b. But, how can I assign a label to the whole of the problem like \label{equ: problem1}?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It is my pleasure to be a member of TeX.SE. :) @Mico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `\label` just after  `\begin{subequations}`, but before the `align`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{equ: problem1}
\begin{align}
& \min_{x} X                                        \label{equ: problem1-a}, \\
\textit{subject to:} & \nonumber \\ 
& x_i \in \{0,1\}  \forall {i \in V}                \label{equ: problem1-b}\\ 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}  
See equations \eqref{equ: problem1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've got it. before your answer, I tried to label it after align.